# How does a Laravel Controller call Authorize function?

Tags: laravel-9

Looking at the laravel docs for controllers, they have an example where they authorize actions via a policy inside a Controller class:

```
$this->authorize('action',$model);
```

Yet checking the laravel doc api, I can see that the base controller class has no authorize method. How does this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I take a look at a standard controller that is scaffolded by Laravel, you'll see that it extends a "base" controller in your `app/Http/Controllers` folder;

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class YourController extends Controller
{
    //...
```

If you go and take a look at this "base" `Controller` class:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
```

You can see that this is using the `AuthorizesRequests` trait.

If you go and take a look in the `AuthorizesRequests` trait you'll see these authorisation methods.

One of which is:

```php
public function authorize($ability, $arguments = [])
{
    [$ability, $arguments] = $this->parseAbilityAndArguments($ability, $arguments);

    return app(Gate::class)->authorize($ability, $arguments);
}
```

This is how the `authorize` method works and is provided to your controllers.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I was looking the wrong place. It extends the Controller.php that comes by default with laravel in your working directory, not the Controller class they have in their docs. That clears it up